# unzipping .gz file in iOS 8

Tags: ios8, gzip

I have an app in which am unzip a .gz file, it is working fine on iOS 7, when i tried the same in iOS 8, am facing issue in unzipping it, gzopen of zlib.h is always nil. Here is the code:

---

```
(void)unzipFileCustom
{
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* dPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* zippedDBPath = [dPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.sqlite.gz"] ;
NSString *unzippedDBPath = [dPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.sqlite"];

//gzfile is always nil
gzFile file = gzopen([zippedDBPath UTF8String], "rb");
FILE *dest = fopen([unzippedDBPath UTF8String], "w");

unsigned char buffer[CHUNK];
int uncompressedLength;

while ((uncompressedLength = gzread(file, buffer, CHUNK)) ) {
    // got data out of our file

    if(fwrite(buffer, 1, uncompressedLength, dest) != uncompressedLength || ferror(dest)) {
       NSLog(@"error writing data");
    }
}
fclose(dest);
gzclose(file);
NSLog(@"Finished unzipping database");
}
```

Comment: Add error checking and report the errors using `strerror()`.

Comment: NSLog(@"error is : %s", strerror(errno));
error is : No such process

Comment: And what function is causing that error?

Comment: gzFile file = gzopen([zippedDBPath UTF8String], "rb");
if am trying to print gzfile object, its returning nil

Comment: just verified, logging strerror(errno) giving me, no such process.

Comment: OK `strerror()` is only valid for `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, etc.  For gzip function errors use `gzerror()` (after `gzopen()` succeeds).  I think that `b` in the mode is invalid (only memory or invalid *mode* can make `gzopen()` fail).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62757/discussion-between-syed-ismail-ahamed-and-droppy).